# Databind to specific Field in DataRowView

Tags: c#, winforms

Given a DataTable with various Columns (`primaryKey, Name, Prefix, NumberSuffix`) I sucessfully bound it to a ComboBox

```
DataTable dt = [DataTable From Database];
MyComboBox.DataSource = dt;
MyComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

I also successfully work with the various fields where needed like so:

```
DataRowView r = MyComboBox.SelectedItem;
MyLabel.Text = $"{r.Row.Field<string>("Prefix")}{r.Row.Field<int>("Number")}{r.Row.Field<string>("Suffix")}";
```

Now I am attempting to Databind one Field of the selected Item in MyCombobox to an Integer of another class `setting` with the field `int primaryKey`

```
MyComboBox.DataBindings.Add("primaryKey", setting, "primaryKey");
```

This fails. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

**Edit:** just noticed a really relevant Detail that I omitted in the above Description.

The mentioned class `setting` is contained in a BindingSource because I am attempting to build a Form where I'm creating various setting files that later will be used by my Application to behave accordingly.

All my other Databindings work as intended Just while trying to bind the ID of the datatable to the ID in the setting and more importantly: selecting the correct DataRow when loading an existing setting I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a Solution. The key part is to store the entire Object in the settings Class.
Consider this Classes:

```cs
    public class ClassA
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; private set; }
        public ClassB classB { get; set; }

        private static int Id = 0;
        public ClassA(string name,ClassB classB)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.classB = classB;
            id = ++Id;
        }

    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public string @value { get; set; }
        public string pre { get; set; }
        public ClassB(string @value, string pre)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.pre = pre;
        }
    }
```

One thing I noticed here and was not clear for me is, that I can only databind to **properties**.

And then in the Form:

```cs
        BindingSource bsClassA = new BindingSource();
        BindingSource bsClassB = new BindingSource();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bsClassB.Add(new ClassB("walue 1","pre1-"));
            bsClassB.Add(new ClassB("walue 2","pre2-"));
            bsClassB.Add(new ClassB("walue 3","pre3-"));

            bsClassA.Add(new ClassA("Test1", (ClassB)bsClassB[0]));
            bsClassA.Add(new ClassA("Test2", (ClassB)bsClassB[1]));
            bsClassA.Add(new ClassA("Test3", (ClassB)bsClassB[2]));

            LiBo_MyList.DataSource = bsClassA;
            LiBo_MyList.DisplayMember = "Name";

            Tx_Id.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsClassA, "id");

            Cb_MyDataset.DataSource = bsClassB;
            Cb_MyDataset.DisplayMember = "value";
            L_MyLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsClassB, "pre");
            Cb_MyDataset.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", bsClassA, "classB");

        }
```

Here I now maintain two separate BindingSources. The key is in the last line. It is now possible to bind the SelectedItem of the combobox to the ClassB of ClassA.

Please notice that this still feels like a workaround. I'd rather just store the ID of the relevant Data and fetch the data elsewere once I need it.